# How to change app language immediately without restart in app settings in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, localization, uikit

I have a settings screen in my SwiftUI app where users can toggle between different languages. The toggle switches work as expected, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to change the language of the app on the fly once the user selects a new language. Currently, the language only updates when the user restarts the app.

Here is the code for my Languages view:

```
struct Languages: View {
    
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    @State var currentSysLanguage = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "language")
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            Group {
                DoubleTextView(topText: LocalizedStringKey("languages"), buttomText: "", topTextSize: 24, buttomTextSize: 0)
            }
            
            Group {
                ZStack {
                    Toggle(isOn: .init(get: {
                        currentSysLanguage == "en"
                    }, set: { isOn in
                        currentSysLanguage = isOn ? "en" : String(Locale.preferredLanguages[0].prefix(2))
                    })) {
                        Text("English")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.custom("Manrope-Bold", size: 16))
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color("active")))
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 10.0)
                .background(Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color("navigation"))
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .cornerRadius(8))
            }
            
            ZStack {
                Toggle(isOn: .init(get: {
                    currentSysLanguage == "ru"
                }, set: { isOn in
                    currentSysLanguage = isOn ? "ru" : String(Locale.preferredLanguages[0].prefix(2))
                })) {
                    Text("Русский")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.custom("Manrope-Bold", size: 16))
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color("active")))
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 10.0)
            .background(Rectangle()
                .fill(Color("navigation"))
                .frame(height: 50)
                .cornerRadius(8))
            
            Group {
                ZStack {
                    Toggle(isOn: .init(get: {
                        currentSysLanguage == "fr"
                    }, set: { isOn in
                        currentSysLanguage = isOn ? "fr" : String(Locale.preferredLanguages[0].prefix(2))
                    })) {
                        Text("Français")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.custom("Manrope-Bold", size: 16))
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color("active")))
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                .background(Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color("navigation"))
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .cornerRadius(8))
                
                ZStack {
                    Toggle(isOn: .init(get: {
                        currentSysLanguage == "es"
                    }, set: { isOn in
                        currentSysLanguage = isOn ? "es" : String(Locale.preferredLanguages[0].prefix(2))
                    })) {
                        Text("Español")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.custom("Manrope-Bold", size: 16))
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color("active")))
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                .background(Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color("navigation"))
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .cornerRadius(8))
            }
            
            ZStack {
                Toggle(isOn: .init(get: {
                    currentSysLanguage == "ko"
                }, set: { isOn in
                    currentSysLanguage = isOn ? "ko" : String(Locale.preferredLanguages[0].prefix(2))
                })) {
                    Text("한국어")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.custom("Manrope-Bold", size: 16))
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color("active")))
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            .background(Rectangle()
                .fill(Color("navigation"))
                .frame(height: 50)
                .cornerRadius(8))
            
            ZStack {
                Toggle(isOn: .init(get: {
                    currentSysLanguage == "ja"
                }, set: { isOn in
                    currentSysLanguage = isOn ? "ja" : String(Locale.preferredLanguages[0].prefix(2))
                })) {
                    Text("やまと")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.custom("Manrope-Bold", size: 16))
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color("active")))
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            .background(Rectangle()
                .fill(Color("navigation"))
                .frame(height: 50)
                .cornerRadius(8))
            
            ZStack {
                Toggle(isOn: .init(get: {
                    currentSysLanguage == "zh-Hans"
                }, set: { isOn in
                    currentSysLanguage = isOn ? "zh-Hans" : String(Locale.preferredLanguages[0])
                })) {
                    Text("中国")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.custom("Manrope-Bold", size: 16))
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color("active")))
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            .background(Rectangle()
                .fill(Color("navigation"))
                .frame(height: 50)
                .cornerRadius(8))
            
            ZStack {
                Toggle(isOn: .init(get: {
                    currentSysLanguage == "id"
                }, set: { isOn in
                    currentSysLanguage = isOn ? "id" : String(Locale.preferredLanguages[0].prefix(2))
                })) {
                    Text("Indonesia")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.custom("Manrope-Bold", size: 16))
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color("active")))
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            .background(Rectangle()
                .fill(Color("navigation"))
                .frame(height: 50)
                .cornerRadius(8))
            
            ZStack {
                Toggle(isOn: .init(get: {
                    currentSysLanguage == "pt-BR"
                }, set: { isOn in
                    currentSysLanguage = isOn ? "pt-BR" : String(Locale.preferredLanguages[0])
                })) {
                    Text("Português (Brasil)")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.custom("Manrope-Bold", size: 16))
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color("active")))
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            .background(Rectangle()
                .fill(Color("navigation"))
                .frame(height: 50)
                .cornerRadius(8))
            
            Group {
                ZStack {
                    Toggle(isOn: .init(get: {
                        currentSysLanguage == "it"
                    }, set: { isOn in
                        currentSysLanguage = isOn ? "it" : String(Locale.preferredLanguages[0].prefix(2))
                    })) {
                        Text("Italiano")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.custom("Manrope-Bold", size: 16))
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color("active")))
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                .background(Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color("navigation"))
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .cornerRadius(8))
                
                ZStack {
                    Toggle(isOn: .init(get: {
                        currentSysLanguage == "de"
                    }, set: { isOn in
                        currentSysLanguage = isOn ? "de" : String(Locale.preferredLanguages[0].prefix(2))
                    })) {
                        Text("Deutsch")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.custom("Manrope-Bold", size: 16))
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: Color("active")))
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                .background(Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color("navigation"))
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .cornerRadius(8))
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
            Alert(
                title: Text(NSLocalizedString("later", comment: "")),
                primaryButton: .destructive(Text(NSLocalizedString("Ok", comment: "")), action: {
                    exit(0)
                }),
                secondaryButton: .cancel(Text(NSLocalizedString("laterButton", comment: "")), action: { // 1
                    
                    
                })
            )
        }
        .background(
            Image("background2")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        )
        .onChange(of: currentSysLanguage, perform: { newValue in
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "language")
            showingAlert = true
        })
        .padding(.top, 40)
        .overlay (
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    
                    self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.system(size: 24))
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
                .padding(.horizontal, 3.0)
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
        )
        .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .padding(.horizontal, 10.0)
    }
}
```

I was trying to use Bundle.main, but it didn't help. I have everywhere a LocalizedStringKey(). All of the answers in here are about UIKit and ViewControllers. I am using SwiftUI, so it won't help.

Comment: Changing language would have little to do with the UI framework. Basically button presses

Comment: So how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: I made that comment because if you have found a UIKit solution the only difference would be the actual button press. Everything else would stay the same. You have a whole lot of code but at the same time no attempt to actually perform the task you want. When you have an actual attempt we can help troubleshoot.

Comment: I suggest you restructure your code. It is mad to do `Toggle(isOn:..)` for **every** language. Look into `ForEach` or something similar.

Comment: Check some tutorials for "on the fly language change swiftui" for example: https://medium.com/swlh/swiftui-localization-on-the-fly-2312fde49459

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).